# The "ManifestMerger" task failed unexpectedly - Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Got new laptop and installed Visual studio 2019.

Below is configuration.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.6
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.11.6+31829.152
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.11.94.52318
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.11.94.52318
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   3.11.0-4.21403.6+ae1fff344d46976624e68ae17164e0607ab68b10
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.2.6 (master@34d6af2)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

IntelliCode Extension   1.0
IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   16.10.15 (552afdf)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   5.11.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

TypeScript Tools   16.0.30526.2002
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   3.11.0-4.21403.6+ae1fff344d46976624e68ae17164e0607ab68b10
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   16.11.0-beta.21514.6+b6c2c4f53ea3a08fa603ea93d6d2f808a62a21d1
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Foo   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

Xamarin   16.11.000.190 d16-11@2391ed9
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   16.11.0.47 (remotes/origin/d16-11@e0d612363)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   16.10.5 (355b57a)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   12.0.0.3 (d16-11/f0e3c2d)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
Mono: c633fe9
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-11@476bb5b
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/v7.0.1@912d149
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.35.4@85460d3
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-11@87af37b

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   15.0.0.8 (0796d78dc)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

---

Created a xamarin forms project but getting below error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ManifestMerger" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\skumbhar\source\repos\App4\App4\App4.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\AndroidManifest.xml.tmp'.
File name: 'C:\Users\skumbhar\source\repos\App4\App4\App4.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\AndroidManifest.xml.tmp'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument..ctor(String templateFilename)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestMerger.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App4.Android
```

---

Tried to clean, rebuild project
Modify VS 2019 edition
Reinstalled VS 2019

But non worked. Could anybody guide me on how to resolve it.

Thanks,
Sandip